# Integrate group page with Facebook SDK 3.0

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0, facebook-group

I need to integrate a facebook group page in my android application. Now, I can login/logout to facebook thanks to the tutorial on the facebook developer website but I don't find any way to show a group page without the using of a webview. Does the facebook SDK provide any way to do this or should I work with the Facebook Graph API  and "rebuild" the group page?

Answer (score 0):

You can go the hard way and dive deep into the *Facebook Graph API*, or you can call the official facebook app to view your group. 
Doing so is pretty easily done:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/513783345316342"));
startActivity(i);
```

Note that you should check first if the official facebook app is actually installed, it will crash otherwise.